# Making a Deleted folder Impossible to Recover

Tags: security, privacy, shred, data-destruction

Suppose you visit a bad location on earth with your laptop.
Thieves are about to break in and steal your laptop.

So you run :

```
rm -rf /folder
```

but what if thieves have very advanced tools to recover deleted files ?
perhaps as advanced as FBI / CIA tools.

Perhaps they will be able to recover that deleted folder w/ files ?

What would be the a way to ensure they can not ?

Answer (score 5):

Just use `shred` like this:

```
$ shred -fuvz /folder
```

The switches above are:

> -f, --force
>
> -u, --remove
>
> -v, --verbose
>
> -z, --zero write to hide the shred

By default `shred` will overwrite three iterations with random data.  This happens before the `-z` writes zeros to hide the shred.  You can specify a different number of iterations with the `-n` switch followed by a digit.  Or in long form with `--iterations=N`.

**A word of caution from the *shred manpages*:**

> **CAUTION:** Note that shred relies on a very important assumption: that the file system overwrites data in place.
> This is the  traditional  way  to  do  things, but many modern file system designs do not satisfy this assumption.
> The following are examples of file systems on which shred is not effective, or is not guaranteed to be effective in all file system modes:
>
> - log-structured or journaled file systems, such as those supplied with AIX and Solaris (and JFS, ReiserFS, XFS, Ext3, etc.)
> - file systems that write redundant data and carry on even if some writes fail, such as RAID-based file systems
> - file systems that make snapshots, such as Network Appliance's NFS server
> - file systems that cache in temporary locations, such as NFS version 3 clients
> - compressed file systems
>
> In the case of ext3 file systems, the above disclaimer applies (and shred is thus of limited effectiveness) only in  data=journal mode, which journals file data in addition to just metadata. In both the data=ordered (default) and data=writeback modes, shred works as usual. Ext3 journaling modes can be changed by adding the data=something option to the mount options for  a  particular file system in the /etc/fstab file, as documented in the mount man page (man mount).
>
> In  addition, file system backups and remote mirrors may contain copies of the file that cannot be removed, and that will allow a shredded file to be recovered later.